# What's wrong with my code with Angular and Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get data from API and bind it to my "headline" property as shown in below code. But what I wrote in the "callback" function:
this.headline = res;

does not work, the headline is not bound.
However, if I put the same code in the fetchData method, it works! But to me it seems there is no difference? 
I'm new to Typescript, what am I doing wrong here?

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent {
    public news: News[];
    public headline: News;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        var headurl = this.baseUrl + "api/News/Headline?country=us&category=business";
        this.fetchData(headurl, function (res) {
            //this code does not work
            this.headline = res;
        });

    }

    fetchData(url, callback) {
        this.http.get<News>(url).subscribe(result => {
            callback(result);
            //this code works!
            this.headline = result;
        }, error => console.error(error));

    }
}


interface News {
    SourceId: string;
    SourceName: string;
    Author: string;
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    Url: string;
    UrlToImage: string;
    PublishedAt: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an arrow function so that `this` is captured when the callback occurs.

```
ngOnInit() {
    var headurl = this.baseUrl + "api/News/Headline?country=us&category=business";
    this.fetchData(headurl, (res) => {
        this.headline = res;
    });
}
```

---

A better design would be to return an `Observable` to the caller instead of passing a callback to the the method being called and let the caller decide how to handle the result.

```
ngOnInit() {
    var headurl = this.baseUrl + "api/News/Headline?country=us&category=business";
    this.fetchData(headurl).subscribe((res) => {
        this.headline = res;
    });
}

fetchData(url) : Observable<News> {
    return this.http.get<News>(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An arrow function captures `this` from the declaration context while a regular function does not and has `this` dependent on the caller (basically the caller decides what `this` to send to the function)

Use the `noImplicitThis` or `strict` (although strict turn on a lot more options) compiler options to avoid such errors.

To fix this particular issue also use an arrow function for the first call :

```
ngOnInit() {
    var headurl = this.baseUrl + "api/News/Headline?country=us&category=business";
    this.fetchData(headurl, (res) => {

        this.headline = res;
    });

}
```